# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x99 in position 5289: invalid start byte

Tags: mysql, django, sqlite, django-models, mysql-connector

For my website in Python, before changing my database from SQLite to MySQL I saved it as a JSON file :

```
python manage.py dumpdata > datadump.json
```

Then I changed my settings.py to the MySQL database to migrate it:

```
python manage.py loaddata datadump.json
```

But it causes this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\M.Hawa\Desktop\My_Django_Stuff\firstproject\deneme\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\json.py", line 67, in Deserializer
    stream_or_string = stream_or_string.decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x99 in position 5289: invalid start byte
```

I tried to change :

```
stream_or_string = stream_or_string.decode()
```

To:

```
stream_or_string = stream_or_string.decode("UTF-16")
```

But it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

In these character sets: armscii8, dec8, greek, hebrew, hp8, latin2, latin5, latin7, tis620, 0x99 represents `™`; is that what you expected?

Is the code in Python?  Is it a literal in the code?  If so, have you stated that Python is using utf8?  (Apparently not.)  Or did the value come from somewhere else?  Where?

See "best practice" in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

I thought JSON only allowed utf8; check the usage of it for that dump.